# I have a Radeon 6450 with 1 DVI port, but I need to be able to 2 monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, upgrade, dvi, amd-radeon

I am upgrading my video card which has a HDMI and DVI-I port according to the pin out on it, but a DVI to VGA adapter does not work, so I figure it has the DVI-I port, but it uses the DVI-d signal. I need to be able to use my two monitors as an extended desktop, is there a way to do this without buying like a converter or any other special hardware?

I was thinking, since all of our monitors we have use VGA connections, buying a DVI to dms-59 adapter, than plugging in the dms59 adapter that cane with the pc that has 2 VGA connections. Will that work how I am looking to set things up? The only reason I ask is because I have only been able to find a DVI to dms59(x2) adapters and I thought using that would split the signal too much?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says yes:

"AMD Eyefinity multi-display technology" "◦Native support for up to 3 simultaneous displays"

http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6450/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6450-overview.aspx#2

AMD Eyefinity Technology:

http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/AMD-EYEFINITY-TECHNOLOGY/Pages/eyefinity.aspx (has a link to the following "how to")

How To:

http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/how-to.aspx

Comment: Please come back and mark as answered if this answered your question.